# With ggplot2, is there a way to only label plot points of one line when using a multi-line plot design?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, label, multiline

I have plotted 2 lines on a graph using ggplot, specially using the "select" and "gather" tools to collapse the two line variables into key-value pairs using this method (solution 2 on here): https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-create-a-ggplot-with-multiple-lines/

Everything works except I can't figure out how label the points of just ONE line using the "Desc" variable. The following code labels both lines with the Desc variable, but I only want to label the "elevation" line. Any ideas?

```
#preparing data
library("tidyverse")
df <- mydatacsv %>%
select(Meter, Stem_Height,Elevation,Desc) %>%
gather(key = "Legend", value = "value", -Meter,-Desc)
head(df,n=200)


# Visualization
ggplot(df, aes(x = Meter, y = value,label=Desc)) + 
geom_line(aes(color = Legend)) + 
scale_color_manual(values = c("green4","black")) +
geom_point(data=mydatacsv, aes(y = Stem_Height),color="green4")+
geom_point(data=mydatacsv, aes(y = Elevation),color="black")+
xlab("Distance (m)") +
ylab("Elevation (m)")+
geom_text_repel(max.overlaps=Inf,hjust=-0.1, angle=90)
```

I wanted two lines plotted, with plot point labels for just one  line. Instead it is putting double-labels on the graph, one for each plot point on each line.

Answer (score 2):

You could label the desired group only in at least three ways.

Using example data `mtcars` and plotting `hp` vs `mpg` for each `gear` level, but labelling only observations for cars with three gears:

1. setting the label text according to the value of gear:

```
    mtcars |>
      ggplot() +
      geom_text(aes(hp, mpg, label = ifelse(gear == 3, mpg, NA)))
```

2. feeding a label layer its own subset of data:

```
    mtcars |>
      ggplot() +
      geom_text(data = mtcars |> filter(gear == 3),
                aes(hp, mpg, label = mpg)
                )
```

3. setting `alpha` (opacity) to zero for unwanted labels:

```
mtcars |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_text(aes(hp, mpg, label = mpg, alpha = gear == 3)) +
  scale_alpha_identity()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `tidyverse` packages, mutate the labels you don't want to either `NA` or blanks `""`. Any of the two will remove the labels of one line, `NA`'s will issue a warning.
I assume you have the data in the [long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format). Though you have reshaped it in the beginning of the question's code, you plot it as if it were not.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(ggrepel)
})

# reproducible test data
set.seed(2023)
df1 <- replicate(2, cumsum(rnorm(20))) |> as.data.frame()
df1$Legend <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = 10L)
df1$Desc <- with(df1, ave(V1, Legend, FUN = \(x) paste("text", seq_along(x))))
names(df1)[1:2] <- c("Meter", "value")
head(df1)
#>         Meter      value Legend   Desc
#> 1 -0.08378436 -0.4116530      A text 1
#> 2 -1.06672810 -0.7059802      A text 2
#> 3 -2.94179542  0.5125938      A text 3
#> 4 -3.12794008  0.7567052      A text 4
#> 5 -3.76142578  0.3115533      A text 5
#> 6 -2.67062832 -1.5362504      A text 6

df1 %>%
  # mutate(Desc = ifelse(Legend == "A", Desc, NA_character_)) %>%
  mutate(Desc = ifelse(Legend == "A", Desc, "")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Meter, value, color = Legend, label = Desc)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(max.overlaps=Inf,hjust=-0.1, angle=90) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green4", "black")) +
  xlab("Distance (m)") +
  ylab("Elevation (m)") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>